# How do I set the conditional statement in this program?

Tags: java

So this code asks for a name and a number 1-20, but if you put in a number over 20 or below 1 the program still runs and I know I need a conditional statement right around figuring out the amount for "ano" to stop and re-ask the statement and re-run the segment but I don't know how to implement it into the code.

```js
// library - for interactive input
import java.util.Scanner;

//---------------------------------
// program name header
public class feb24a
{
  //--------FUNCTION CODING ---------------
  // FUNCTION HEADER
  public static void seeit(String msg, String aname, int ano)
  {
    // statement to accomplish the task of this function
    System.out.print("\n The message is " + msg + "\t" + "Name is:" + aname + "\t" + "number is: " + ano);
    // return statement without a variable name because it is a void
    return;
  }

  //-------------------  MAIN MODULE CODING TO CALL FUNCTIONS ----------------
  // Main module header
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {          
    String msg, aname;
    int ano, again, a, b;

    msg = "Hello";
    a = 1;
    b = 20;

    //Loop control variable
    again = 2;           
    while(again == 2)
    {
       System.out.print("\n enter NAME: ");      
       Scanner username = new Scanner(System.in);
  
       aname = username.nextLine();
  
       System.out.print("\n enter number 1-20: ");      
       Scanner userno = new Scanner(System.in);
  
       ano = userno.nextInt();
       seeit(msg, aname, ano);
 
       //ask user if they want to do it again, 2 for yes any other for no
       System.out.print("\n do you want to do this again? 2 for yes ");
  
       Scanner useragain = new Scanner(System.in);      
       again = useragain.nextInt();
     } //terminate the while loop
   }     
 }
```

Comment: ints a and b were from when I tried to insert an "if then" statement

Comment: You simply have to use eg : if (i >0 && i<= 20)

Comment: It looks like you used an icon labeled "Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet" to enter your question.  Javascript is not Java.  Please don't do that.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I misread that when I was entering in the question. It won't happen again. @ajb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your while loop with this:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (again == 2) {
        ano = 0;

        System.out.print("\n enter NAME: ");
        aname = scanner.nextLine();

        while (ano < 1 || ano > 20) {
            System.out.print("\n enter number 1-20: ");
            ano = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        seeit(msg, aname, ano);

        System.out.print("\n do you want to do this again? 2 for yes ");
        again = scanner.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, now I just need to deconstruct it and see how this works for future use!

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround your ano = userno.nextInt() in a while loop.  (i.e., while(ano < 1 || ano > 20)) and put a prompt inside that while loop.  That way, it will keep reading a new number until it finally no longer fulfills the while loop and will break out.

Comment: I tried surrounding the "ano = username.nextLine();" inside of the while loop that you suggested but wouldn't ano have not been defined yet?

Comment: I fixed my answer to replace the && with ||.  No, ano would still be defined.  You would remove the outer while loop, just add an inner while loop, like Pavlo has demonstrated above.